# Angular Meteor - Displaying username instead of UserID

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I managed to show UserID of the poster on the front-end and I tried many different things to show username instead of ID. Can't find what's wrong or what to do.

The form to post

```
    <form ng-show="$root.currentUser">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input ng-model="newPost.name">
    <label>Description</label>
    <input ng-model="newPost.description">
    <button ng-click="newPost.owner=$root.currentUser._id; posts.push(newPost)">Add</button>    
    </form>
```

Controller

```
    angular.module('posts').controller('PostsCtrl', ['$scope', '$meteor',
function($scope, $meteor){

    $scope.posts = $meteor.collection(Posts);
    $scope.remove = function(post){
        $scope.posts.remove(post);
    };
}]);
```

Model:

```
    Posts = new Mongo.Collection("posts");    
        Posts.allow({
            insert: function (userId, post) {
                return userId && post.owner === userId;
            },
            update: function (userId, post, fields, modifier) {
                return userId && post.owner === userId;
            },
            remove: function (userId, post) {
                return userId && post.owner === userId;
    }
    });
```

**EDIT:**
Html:

```
    <p class="post-user">{{post.owner}}</p>
```

Now it all works but this time it's showing user-ID instead of the username.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Knowing only these few lines of your code I would say almost nothing is correct. Where is $root defined in the scope? Where is the controller used in the HTML code? Why do you want to hide the form and not the surrounding div or whatever? Why do you set post.owner to the user id but use post.username in your html paragraph? Perhaps that's all done by meteor with I do not know but I doubt that. Give your browser tools (type F12 key in the browser window; at least on Chrome and Firefox) a try. If there are errors you can see it in the console tab.

Comment: I thought HTML was irrelevant since everything works like a charm but I fail to show the username... I.e: Only the post creator can delete the post. It's working, but not the name. I'll check the console again and paste my full code then... Thanks.

Comment: maybe you cannot use `$root` in `ng-click` but have to call a method and use `$rootScope`. please try that. see this question for a usage example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693154/is-it-possible-to-use-getreactively-on-rootscope-variables

Comment: Hi. Clicks are working. I just tried {{post.owner}} and it shows me the user ID. Updating the question now.

Comment: Can I ask why you are using Meteor and AngularJS together? That sounds like a recipe for disaster straight off the bat to me. The two are fundamentally different. ReactJS is a much better companion for Meteor.

Comment: Hi Brian . I'm a newbie and I'm trying to learn but I really don't know... I tried meteor first, now I'm trying with Angular. I'll also check ReactJS. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think that everything else is correct then, try this: `<p class="post-user">{{post.owner}}</p>`. As I said, I do not know meteor and perhaps your code is right. But when you add a post, you set the `owner` attribute to the users name. I can not find a place where you set `newPost.username`.

Comment: I just tried {{post.owner}} and it shows me the user ID. Updating the question now.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the default structure of the Meteor's User object if you scroll down this step:
http://angular-meteor.com/tutorial/step_09

Where are you defining the username?  if you are not defining it, it won't be anywhere.
Usually the user information is saved under the "profile" key, but it depends on the service you are using to login (Facebook, Email-Password) and your own implementation of saving the user's data.